# Secondary articulation in Russian

Tags: согласные

Is it correct to say that *all* Russian consonants are subject to secondary articulation: the *soft* ones are palatalized, whereas the *hard* ones are velarized?

Comment: What do you mean by velarized? Soft х is voiceless velar fricative (just like the hard х).

Answer (score 2):

Most but not all:

- **й**, **ч** and **щ** are always soft
- **ж**, **ш** and **ц** are always hard.

Comment: Do you mean that these do not have phonetically possible hard/soft counterparts?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. Phonetically they *can* have hard/soft pairs. E.g. in Ukrainian ц is always soft: Східниця. In fact, ш/щ are one such pair within Russian. But they just don't follow the same rules of positional softening as the rest of the consonants. E.g. рука - руке (к is softened) but ноша - ноше (ш does not become щ). So they are a pair phonetically but not morphophonologically. If you know what I mean. :)

Comment: With the exception of **й** which is pure softness itself. I can't imagine what its hard counterpart would sound like.

Comment: As far as I understand, й is a semivowel, so it is rather different from other consonants. What surprised me is the claim that **all** the consonants in Russian experience secondary articulation, as opposed to *normal* consonants in English(?). I am wondering how much of this view owes to English-speakers dominating linguistics in the last half of the century.

Comment: @SergeySlepov the hard counterpart of й is Ukrainian/South Russian fricative г or voiced х. Compare её/его, сей/сего (его and сего formerly were pronounced with fricative г)

Comment: @Vadim no й is not semivowel, it is like other consonants. It is a voiced counterpart to soft х or fricative counterpart of soft г.

Comment: @SergeySlepov - Ukrainian does have a hard/soft pair of _ц_ and _ць_: hard [t͡s]: цей [t͡sɛj] 'this (masc.)', цим [t͡sɪm] 'with this', цирк [t͡sɪrk] circus, цап [t͡sap] 'he-goat', цукор [ˈt͡sukɔr] 'sugar'; soft [t͡sʲ]: ці [t͡sʲi] 'these', ця [t͡sʲa] 'this (fem.)', цю [t͡sʲu] 'this' [fem. acc.], місяць [ˈmisʲat͡sʲ] 'month'. On the other hand, the soft long (gemminated) [t͡sʲː] (міццю [ˈmit͡sʲːu] 'with strength' (instr. sg.)) doesn't have a hard long counterpart [t͡sː] in Slavic words, but it's present in some Italian borrowings: інтермеццо [intɛrˈmɛt͡sːɔ] 'intermezzo', піцца [ˈpit͡sːa] 'pizza'.

Comment: @YellowSky, thanks for the corrections. Agreed.